# JS: what's the different in Promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise, nodes

I just wonder if there is different between those 2 calls by `await Promise.all([/* ... /*])`
In my performance test, it took the same time.

This is my method to be invoked by the Promise.all:

```
const makeFetch1 = async () => {
  axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
};

const makeFetch2 = async () => {
  return axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
};

1) await Promise.all([makeFetch1(), makeFetch1(), ...])
2) await Promise.all([makeFetch2(), makeFetch2(), ...])
```

Both have the same execution time result, what i should choose?

Comment: Note that the first arrow function doesn't return anything beyond the async wrapper promise. Only single-statement arrow functions return data, the moment you have a function body inside curly brackets you need a `return` keyword.

Comment: if you don't `return` anything in an async function, it returns a promise with an `undefined` value.

Comment: There's no point in using `Promise.all()` with the first one because it's not monitoring any promises at all.  It will just resolve immediately while the `fetch()` operations continuing running and eventually finish.  The second one tracks both promises and resolves when they both resolve and also resolves with their values.

Comment: i would add that `[makeFetch1, ...]`, `[makeFetch2, ...]` does not **call** the `makeFetch*` function. you need to write `Promise.all([makeFetch2(), ...])`

Comment: if you are asking what is the performance difference between `(...) => { ... }` and `(...) => ...` go measure it. stackoverflow is not for this kind of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several major differences and multiple coding mistakes.

First off this code:

```
const makeFetch1 = async () => {
  axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
};
```

is an `async` function that calls `axios.get()` and then immediately returns a promise that is already resolved and has an `undefined` resolved value.  Nothing here waits for the `axios.get()` call to finish.

Your second code block:

```
const makeFetch2 = async () => {
  return axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
};
```

calls `axios.get()` and returns the promise that it creates.  So, the promise this function returns will be tied to when the `axios.get()` call completes and the resolved value will be the resolved value of the axios call.

Differences:

1. You could use the `makeFetch2()` function to get the result of the `axios.get()` call (resolved value or reject error).  You could not use `makeFetch1()` to get the result of the `axios.get()` call because that result is not communicated back to the caller in any way.
2. Similarly, `makeFetch2()` will allow the caller to know when the axios operation has completed.  `makeFetch1()` will not.
3. If the `axios.get()` operation rejected, then `makeFetch1()` would result in an unhandled rejection error because nothing is listening for the rejection.

Then, these two:

```
await Promise.all([makeFetch1, makeFetch1, ...])
await Promise.all([makeFetch2, makeFetch2, ...])
```

Are both pretty useless because you're not calling any of the functions so nothing is executing.  These will both just resolve immediately with a resolved value of an array of function references.  None of the axios calls are executed because nothing actually calls `makeFetch1()` or `makeFetch2()`.

---

If you meant to actually execute the functions with these two:

```
await Promise.all([makeFetch1(), makeFetch1(), ...])
await Promise.all([makeFetch2(), makeFetch2(), ...])
```

Then, the first one just resolves immediately with an array of `undefined` values as the resolved value because remember the `makeFetch1()` return value isn't connected in any way to the `axios.get()` call.

The second one will properly wait for all the `axios.get()` calls in `makeFetch2()` to complete and will resolve with an array of values from the `axios.get()` calls.

---

> Both have the same execution time result, what i should choose?

That's because as you've implemented them, you aren't calling the `makeFetchN()` functions in either case.  So, they aren't doing anything and thus have the same execution time.

If you change the implementation to actually call the functions as in:

```
await Promise.all([makeFetch1(), makeFetch1(), ...])
await Promise.all([makeFetch2(), makeFetch2(), ...])
```

There will be a significant timing difference because the one based on `makeFetch1()` does not wait for any of the `axios.get()` calls to finish and does not communicate back results or completion and is subject to uncaught rejections.

The one based on `makeFetch1()` has no practical use as you could just do:

```
makeFetch1();
makeFetch1();
...
```

with the exact same result because `makeFetch1()` just returns an immediately resolved promise so passing them all to `Promise.all()` isn't doing anything useful.

`makeFetch1()` is probably just not useful since it doesn't inform the caller of completion, error or resolved value.

Answer (score 2):

The first one will fire of a request *and not return it*. so `makeFetch1()` will result in a Promise that resolves immediately. This is almost certainly never what you want. An async function should `await` or `return` inside somewhere, otherwise it may as well be a standard function (that returns nothing).

Even if you don't care about what the request resolves to, you should still use the result of the request (by returning or `await`ing, just so you can see if the request succeeds or not - and communicate to the user that there was a problem if it fails)

The second one will fire of a request *and return it*. so `makeFetch1()` will result in a Promise that resolves *once the request resolves* - which is likely to take a number of milliseconds.

Comment: They both have same performance, that true? :)

Comment: @BallonUra They do different things, so it doesn't make sense to compare performance.